# How to activate JavaScript on Blogger template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, drop-down-menu, blogger

I have a dropdown menu and a script to open it when clicked, but when I put that on my template on Blogger it does not execute.

See this: jsfiddle.net/hr0bk4ob/

How do I get the JavaScript to run on my blogspot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the script below, by adding it to your template, before `</body>`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
**Your JavaScript coding here**
//]]>
</script>
```